# Generic function for a family of related functions (e.g. std::stoi, std::stof, std::stod etc)

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like to make a generic function for std::stoi, std::stof, std::stod etc.. like:

```
// std::string -> int
std::string str = "1000000";
int i = to_numeric<int>(str);

// std::string -> long
std::string str = "100000000000";
long i = to_numeric<long>(str);

// std::string -> float
std::string str = "10000.1";
float i = to_numeric<float>(str);
```

But I do not know how to make the partial specialization:

```
template<class T>
int to_numeric(const std::string &str, size_t *pos = 0, int base = 10) {
    return std::stol(str, pos, base);
};

template<>
long to_numeric<long>(const std::string &str, size_t *pos, base) {
    return std::stol(str, pos, base);
};

template<>
float to_numeric<float>(const std::string &str, size_t *pos) {
    return std::stof(str, pos);
};
// .....
```

**Errors:**

```
to_numeric.cpp:76:79: error: default argument specified in explicit specialization [-fpermissive]
to_numeric.cpp:76:12: error: template-id 'to_numeric<float>' for 'float to_numeric(const string&, size_t*)' does not match any template declaration
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Comment: I'd just use `boost::lexical_cast`.

Comment: I'dont have the Boost, but I've C++11 with the same functional

Comment: Since you need to specify the target type, why bother? For generic functions, have the user pass a callback that does the conversion, which might aswell be `std::stoi` and family. Also, since this isn't explicitly about a C++11 feature (you just use one in the implementation, but you could call anything else aswell), I edited the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify a primary template which takes three arguments (`str`, `pos`, and `base`) but you try to specialize it with function templates taking just one argument. Clearly, this doesn't work: The specializations need to match the primary template.

Partial specializations of function templates are not [yet?] supported. If you need a partially specialized function template you need to do the partial specialization indirectly: You'd delegate to a class template and partially specialized that. The class template may have just one `static` function. Of course, in your example you don't use partial specialization but full specialization.

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example?

Comment: @Robbin: A simple example of what...? Fixing your code should be straight forward (add the missing parameters and, as Joachim Pileborg pointed out, give the primary template a return type of `T`) and using partial specialization I have to admit that I wouldn't know where you'd want to use partial specialization in this context!

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, I realized my mistake)

Answer (score 2):

To start with, you have to make the non-specialized template function *fully* templated. That means you have to make the return type `T`. I also recommend that this non-specialized function doesn't do anything more than return e.g. `T()` (since it isn't specialized and don't know what function to call).

To continue, the `to_numeric<float>` specialization needs to have the *same* arguments as the non-specialized function, so you need to add the dummy `base`argument.